# Laravel s3 check if directory exists.

Tags: laravel

How would I check with Laravel `storage` if a directory exists?

In the documentation there is only documented how to check if a file exists.

`Storage::disk('local')->exists('file.jpg');`

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/filesystem#retrieving-files

Comment: Did you find a solution on this? I need to check the actual bucket if exists, not any internal directory or file of the bucket, but the bucket itself!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to get directories list in a parent directory and check if the directory you're looking for is in an array:

```
in_array('directoryYoureLookingFor', Storage::disk('s3')->directories('parentDirectory'));
```

I've just checked and this solution works in Laravel 5.3.

Comment: That will throw an error: ```Call to a member function has() on array```

Comment: Works! Done it like this: ```in_array('users/' . $user->id, Storage::disk('s3')->directories('users'));```

Answer (score 6):

In Laravel 5.7 use:
The `has()` method is used to determine if a given file exists on the disk:

```
$exists = Storage::disk('s3')->has('file.jpg');
```

Comment: OP: "directory"

Answer (score 6):

None of the answers here seems to answer specifically to check if a particular folder exists in S3. This is what I use and it works:

```
Storage::disk('s3')->exists('FOLDER_NAME')
```

The above will return a boolean. The above check works for both folders and filenames.

Answer (score 1):

You can using `isDirectory` method:

```
if (File::isDirectory($filename))
{
    echo "Yes. It's a directory.";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have also faced same issue many time for check file is exists or not on S3 with Laravel. I am working on Laravel 7.* and exists() and has() functions not providing proper response when file is uploaded on sub directory of S3 bucket. I have write a function which is working perfectly for me.

```
public static function fileExistsS3($directoryOnS3, $image) {
    $directoryOnS3 = Config::get('custom.AWS_PUBLIC_ENDPOINT').$directoryOnS3;
    $exists = @getimagesize($directoryOnS3.$image);

    if(isset($exists) && is_array($exists)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

It will return true if file available on S3 else it will return false.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following thing i.e u can get the filename and compare it with the file name urtrying to upload if it exists give a maessage else u  can insert

```
$file = Storage::disk('local')->get($filename);
if($file){
    echo "file exist";
} else {
    Storage::disk('local')->put($filename,FILE::get($file));
}
```